# page styling is not working with flexbox as expected

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, frontend

i am working in a react project where the elements { about, mint , team} should be spread out on the right side of the screen and the logos should be on the left side.

instead they are stuck together as you can see from the image i posted. they should be on the right and the left side.

[image]

code

```
import React from 'react';
import { ChakraProvider, Box, Button, Flex, Image, Link, Spacer } from '@chakra-ui/react';;
import Facebook from "./assets/social-media-icons/facebook_32x32.png";
import Twitter from "./assets/social-media-icons/twitter_32x32.png";
import Email from "./assets/social-media-icons/email_32x32.png";

const NavBar = ({accounts, setAccounts}) => {
    const isConnected = Boolean(accounts[0]);

    async function connectAccount(){
        if(window.ethereum) {
            const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
                method: "eth_requestAccounts",
            });
        setAccounts(accounts);
        }
    }

    return(<ChakraProvider>
        
        <Flex justify="space-between" align="center" padding="30px">
        
            {/*Left Side - Social Media Icons*/}
            <Flex justify="space-around" width="40%" padding="0 75px">
                <Link href="https://www.facebook.com">
                    <Image src={Facebook} boxSize="42px" margin="0 15px"/>
                </Link>
                <Link href="https://www.twitter.com">
                    <Image src={Twitter} boxSize="42px" margin="0 15px"/>
                </Link>
                <Link href="https://www.gmail.com">
                    <Image src={Email} boxSize="42px" margin="0 15px"/>
                </Link>
            </Flex>

            
            {/*Right Side - Sections and Connect*/}
            <Flex justify="space-between" align="center" padding="30px">
            <Box margin="0 15px">About</Box>
            <Spacer />
            <Box margin="0 15px">Mint</Box>
            <Spacer />      
            <Box margin="0 15px">Team</Box>
            <Spacer />
      

            {/*Connect*/}
            { isConnected ? (
                <Box margin="0 15px">Connected</Box>
            ) : (
                <Button 
                backgroundColor="#008fd4"
                borderRadius="15px"
                boxShadow="0px 2px 2px 1px #0F0F0F"
                color="white"
                cursor="pointer"
                fontFamily="inherit"
                padding="15px"
                margin="0 15px"
                onClick={connectAccount}>Connect</Button>
            ) }
        </Flex>
</Flex>
</ChakraProvider>

    );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: Can you share the details about how you can using the FLEX, BOX, LINK tag in component? have you import any component or library for that?

Comment: yes, i am using chakra.                                                                                                                    import { Box, Button, Flex, Image, Link, Spacer } from '@chakra-ui/react';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have two semicolons in you

```
import { ChakraProvider, Box, Button, Flex, Image, Link, Spacer } 
from '@chakra-ui/react';
```

go like this.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to update code as below:

```
import { Box, Button, Flex, Image, Link, Spacer } from '@chakra-ui/react';
```

with

```
import { ChakraProvider, Box, Button, Flex, Image, Link, Spacer } from '@chakra-ui/react';
```

and

`return(`
with `return (<ChakraProvider>`
and
`);` with `</ChakraProvider> );`

so your code look like this:

```
return(<ChakraProvider>
        
        <Flex justify="space-between" align="center" padding="30px">
        
            {/*Left Side - Social Media Icons*/}
            <Flex justify="space-around" width="40%" padding="0 75px">
                <Link href="https://www.facebook.com">
                    <Image src={Facebook} boxSize="42px" margin="0 15px"/>
                </Link>
                <Link href="https://www.twitter.com">
                    <Image src={Twitter} boxSize="42px" margin="0 15px"/>
                </Link>
                <Link href="https://www.gmail.com">
                    <Image src={Email} boxSize="42px" margin="0 15px"/>
                </Link>
            </Flex>

            
            {/*Right Side - Sections and Connect*/}
            <Flex justify="space-between" align="center" padding="30px">
            <Box margin="0 15px">About</Box>
            <Spacer />
            <Box margin="0 15px">Mint</Box>
            <Spacer />      
            <Box margin="0 15px">Team</Box>
            <Spacer />
      

            {/*Connect*/}
            { isConnected ? (
                <Box margin="0 15px">Connected</Box>
            ) : (
                <Button 
                backgroundColor="#008fd4"
                borderRadius="15px"
                boxShadow="0px 2px 2px 1px #0F0F0F"
                color="white"
                cursor="pointer"
                fontFamily="inherit"
                padding="15px"
                margin="0 15px"
                onClick={connectAccount}>Connect</Button>
            ) }
        </Flex>
</Flex>
</ChakraProvider>

    );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: return( with return (<ChakraProvider> and
); with </ChakraProvider> );                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                           where should i put it?

Comment: in import line where you have import the chakra inside that line please add ChakraProvider additionally.
and inside the render where you have added the html, please warp with <ChakraProvider></ChakraProvider> so your all html code going inside this tag

Comment: <ChakraProvider> add inside your return method.

Comment: doing so having this error                                                                                                            Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
ERROR in [eslint]
src\NavBar.js
  Line 3:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 4:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
  Line 5:1:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
better if you could show it in the code.

Comment: please check updated ans and try it.

Comment: same error, have change the code as u suggested.

Comment: have you changed import line as well? import { ChakraProvider, Box, Button, Flex, Image, Link, Spacer } from '@chakra-ui/react';

Comment: yes i have as u suggested

Comment: Can you post whole file code in your question.

Comment: i just add the whole code

Comment: got it, there was two semicolon.